# Cross fading two jit.windows with OpenGL content

Tags: jit, max-msp-jitter

How can I cross fade two `jit.windows`? One has an OpenGL content and the other is just a matrix (webcam capture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the OpenGL content to end up in the same output window as the web cam capture.

I would advise sending the matrix from the webcam input to a jit.gl.texture object, then rendering it with a jit.gl.videoplane, like so:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
348.3ocwSsraCCBD7L9q.wYWKamG8wo7eTEEgsWkPDFr.bhihx+dMKFklFop
V0V0Kf2gcmc7vx4DBqRO.VF8E5qTB4bBgfPd.xTLg0xGpkbKlFSAG0U6Yogi
bvfCg2KbYakYGDMftSxU.ck+rdCPOBU071XEp9VgRBNjshqf5dWDsbBsi6p2
ITa2XfZWPiKVjkmRKJCaOOyuUVlkSWOUi0cRBnhhMTzfgih9gYQrPybm5f.s
d4uok6LhAV5Xoz097tjj3WR+4NSj5eOKX9b+Z36utAT9eY.iiFwwgUJd6ewP
wS43LwxuokT7oVxV4lIceusf7yjB0Ge.gRzieqWY08l5H4S2FzqprArNgh6D
Z06xo3lb1IZZ.737XUBKuRB3+S9chi20c.L1IJQgLdksWa7gOlhgBUHDYjYf
ChX9yPDtYzucils2D7t1vx4rPo5Fvn5E3kVhuyWRdCvmkpvo
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```